# Generating unique Pythagorean triplets using this algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def pyg(n):
    n=int(n)
    for i in range(1,n):
        a=(2*i)+1
        b=(2*i)*(i+1)
        c=(2*i)*(i+1)+1
        return(a,b,c)
```

When i try to run this on Shell using `pyg(100)` I only get output (3, 4, 5).
What might be the problem all the triplets are not generating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As many others pointed out, when the return statement executes, your function will finish, and will not continue looping. However, you have options for returning multiple values from a single function. For example aggregating your values in a list and return that, or to use the `yield` keyword instead of `return`. The `yield` keyword will make your function a *generator function*, which returns an *iterable generator object* with all your expected elements.

I advise you to split your code into separate functions, so you have the original formula as a *function of i*, and a generator function which will return the elements for `1 <= i < n`. Note that you can collect the elements of a generator to a list by supplying it to the `list` constructor.

```
def pyg(i):
  a = (2*i) + 1
  b = (2*i) * (i+1)
  c = (2*i) * (i+1) + 1
  return (a,b,c)

def pygs(n):
  for i in range(1, n):
    yield pyg(i)

print(list(pygs(10))) # prints the first 9 Pythagorean triplet as a list of tuples
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer and add some useful explanation to it. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` sentence. Change it for a `yield`. If you want to test it, you could:

```
>>> pygs = pyg(100)
>>> next(pygs)
(3, 4, 5)
>>> next(pygs)
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function produces only one pair, because `return` interrupts function execution. You could use [`yield`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python) keyword, as suggested by [@jgomo3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32315366/generating-unique-pythagorean-triplets-using-this-algorithm/32315590#32315590), or [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function:

```
def generate_triplet(n):
    a=(2*n)+1
    b=(2*n)*(n+1)
    c=(2*n)*(n+1)+1
    return(a,b,c)

def pyg(n):
    return map(generate_triplet, range(1, int(n))
```